# Optimistic concurrency: IsConcurrencyToken and RowVersion

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, concurrency, ef-code-first

I'm creating the default concurrency strategy that I will use in my application.

I decided for an optimistic strategy.

All of my entities are mapped as `Table per Type (TPT)` (using inheritance). I soon learned that there is a problem when using columns of type RowVersion with inheritance on Entity Framework:

```
Product

Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
RowVersion ROWVERSION

Car (inherits Product records)

Color TYNIINT NOT NULL,
AnotherProperty....
```

If I update a record of the `Car` table the RowVersion column from `Product` table will not be updated.

I plan to use a column of type `datetime2 (7)` in `Product` and update it manually if any records of the tables that inherit this table are modified.

I think I'm reinventing the wheel.

Is there another way to use the optimistic concurrency strategy with `ROWVERSION` when using `Table per Type (TPT)` in Entity Framework?

**Edit**

My mapping:

```
class Product
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

class Car : Product
{
    int Color { get; set; }
}
```

**CodeFirst** conventions.

Only the RowVersion property on `Product` entity has custom definitions:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
    .Property(t => t.RowVersion) 
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

Comment: *Product table will not be updated*. It actually is, with a dummy update that increments rowversion (EF 6.1.3).

Comment: Hi @GertArnold. On my tests (EF6.1.3), rowversion is not incremented.

Comment: OK, maybe you should show your mapping to see if we're on the same page.

Comment: Please, could you post an working code sample? (Working mapping that updates the base class rowversion)

Comment: I can only post code in an answer. I don't think I can answer your question without seeing your mapping. I just used a cookbook TPT mapping.

Comment: Mapping added. @GertArnold

Comment: @GertArnold I had issues trying to get these classes working. First of all I had to make the classes public, and their properties public.  However I then got TPH a single Products table with a discriminator column.

Comment: @kirsteng Not much I can do with this short description. You better explain it more completely in a new question.

Comment: @GertArnold, My question is , shouldn't this question be worded as TPH not TPT ? sorry I didn't make that clear. Should I be asking a new question about this question?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Both in EF6 and EF-core, when working with SQL Server, you have to use this mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>() 
    .Property(t => t.RowVersion) 
    .IsRowVersion(); // Not: IsConcurrencyToken
```

**IsConcurrencyToken** does configure a property as concurrency token, but (when using it for a `byte[]` property)

- the data type is `varbinary(max)`
- its value is always `null` if you don't initialize it
- its value is not auto-incremented when a record is updated.

**[IsRowVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.binarypropertyconfiguration.isrowversion%28v=vs.113%29.aspx)** on the other hand,

- has datatype `rowversion` (in SQL Server, or `timestamp` in earlier versions), so
- its value is never null, and
- its value is always auto-incremented when a record is updated.
- and it automatically configures the property to be an optimistic concurrency token.

Now when you update a `Car` you'll see two update statements:

```sql
DECLARE @p int
UPDATE [dbo].[Product]
SET @p = 0
WHERE (([Id] = @0) AND ([Rowversion] = @1))
SELECT [Rowversion]
FROM [dbo].[Product]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = @0

UPDATE [dbo].[Car]
SET ...
```

The first statement doesn't update anything, but it increments the rowversion, and it will throw a concurrency exception if the rowversion was changed in-between.

The `[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Timestamp]` attribute is the data annotations equivalent of `IsRowVersion()`:

```cs
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

Note that the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) is not correct. It says that `IsConcurrencyToken` is the fluent equivalent of the `[Timestamp]` attribute. However, `IsRowVersion` is the equivalent.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? According to the documentation, IsConcurrencyToken() used on byte[] property should map to rowversion datatype that was added in SQL Server 2005.

Comment: @SørenBoisen This was SQL2012 IIRC. I Just tested it code-first and reported what I got. If the documentation tells something else, it's either wrong, or it presupposes other steps I didn't take. Which documentation do you refer to?

Comment: Okay, perhaps not exactly documentation, but a tutorial on the official site nevertheless :-) Here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/handling-concurrency-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: I can confirm your findings by the way - need to use IsRowVersion to get the proper behaviour.

Comment: The documentation is slightly off indeed. It demonstrates the use of the `[Timestamp]` attribute and then states that `IsConcurrencyToken` is the equivalent fluent method. But that's not true. `IsRowVersion` is equivalent.

Comment: Hi Gert, what should I do if I am adding a RowVersion to a table that already have existing records?

Comment: So in essence, use IsConcurrencyToken  if you want manual control over then token being generated. Use IsRowVersion if you want sql server to handle it automatically. Right?

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of investigating I was able to use IsConcurrencyToken on a byte[8] column called RowVersion in Entity Framework 6.

Because we want to use the same datatype in DB2 ( which doesn't have rowversion in the database itself) we can't use the option IsRowVersion()!

I investigated a little bit  further how to work with IsConcurrencyToken.

I did the following to achieve a solution that seems to work:

My Model:

```
    public interface IConcurrencyEnabled
{
    byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}

  public class Product : AuditableEntity<Guid>,IProduct,IConcurrencyEnabled
{
    public string Name
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public string Description
    {
        get; set;
    }
    private byte[] _rowVersion = new byte[8];
    public byte[] RowVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return _rowVersion;
        }

        set
        {
            System.Array.Copy(value, _rowVersion, 8);
        }
    }
}
```

IConcurrencyEnabled is used to identify Entities that have a rowversion that needs special treatment.

I used fluent API to configure the modelbuilder:

```
    public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        Property(e => e.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        Property(e => e.RowVersion).IsFixedLength().HasMaxLength(8).IsConcurrencyToken();
    }
}
```

And finally I added a method to my derived DBContext class to update the field before the base.SaveChanges is called:

```
        public void OnBeforeSaveChanges(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Modified))
        {
            IConcurrencyEnabled entity = dbEntityEntry.Entity as IConcurrencyEnabled;
            if (entity != null)
            {

                if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
                {
                    var rowversion = dbEntityEntry.Property("RowVersion");
                    rowversion.CurrentValue = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int64)1);
                }
                else if (dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Modified)
                {
                    var valueBefore = new byte[8];
                    System.Array.Copy(dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.GetValue<byte[]>("RowVersion"), valueBefore, 8);

                    var value = BitConverter.ToInt64(entity.RowVersion, 0);
                    if (value == Int64.MaxValue)
                        value = 1;
                    else value++;

                    var rowversion = dbEntityEntry.Property("RowVersion");
                    rowversion.CurrentValue = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int64)value);
                    rowversion.OriginalValue = valueBefore;//This is the magic line!!

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

The problem most people encounter is that after setting the value of the entity, we always get a UpdateDBConcurrencyException, because the OriginalValue has changed... even if it hasn't!

The reason is that for a byte[] both original and currentValue change if you set the CurrentValue alone (?? strange and unexpected behavior).

So I set the OriginalValue again to the original Value before I updated the rowversion...
Also I copy the array to avoid referencing the same byte-array!

Attention: Here I use an incremental approach to change the rowversion, you are free to use your own strategy to fill in this value. (Random or time-based)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not how you are setup. What is happening is that the `OriginalValue` of your `RowVersion` entry is set to the new value as soon as you pull it out of the Context.

```
 var carInstance = dbContext.Cars.First();
 carInstance.RowVersion = carDTO.RowVerison;
 carInstance.Color = carDTO.Color ;


 var entry = dbContext.Entry(carInstance); //Can also come from ChangeTrack in override of SaveChanges (to do it automatically)     

 entry.Property(e => e.RowVersion)
                    .OriginalValue = entry.Entity.RowVersion;
```