# EF Core: How to ensure only one thread is updating a DB having async calls?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using .net core EF and want to ensure that at a time only one thread is executing a certain code block which has logic of updating a data to database :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ApproveEntity([FromBody] Entity[] entities)
    {
        Entity Entity = entities.Where(f => f.isMainEntity == true).First();

        try
        {


            try
            {
                try
                    {
                        if (this.ValidateConcurrencyForWriteBack(Entity))
                        {

                           return this.BadRequest("Concurrency Error : Somebody else has already done this action. Please refresh and try again.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                if (Entity.SupportingDocuments?.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    await this.UploadDocumentsToBlob(Entity, user);
                                    this.Uow.Commit();
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {                                    
                                throw;
                            }

                            await this.BulkChallengeApproveReject(entities, user);
                        }
                    }                     


            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return this.Ok(Entity);
    }
```

I want above block of code should be executed by  one thread at a time.

> I have tried using **Mutext** & **SemaphoreSlim** but not getting the expected result.

The validateConcurrency method will check if record is updated already or not. but it does not prevent thread blocking.

Comment: I think this is an unrealistic requirement, which suggests an architectural error. Any web app which limits a URL to one request at a time will not scale with more than a few users. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @TsahiAsher There are as of now three users who can approve a certain record using above method, what if two users concurrently approved same record then, how would i ensure only one user will update the record and other user will get error.

Comment: Usually the easiapp st way is to write a query that will fail for the second user by specifying what the column being updated should be as a value. If it is already updated by someone else it is no longer that value. `update table set column = 'newvalue' where ID=whatever and column = 'oldvalue'`

Comment: Concurrency check. here is one article to get you started: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency

Comment: The right question would be _Why this SemaphoreSlim doesn't work_

Comment: @CaiusJard usually you would use a `rowversion` type of column (for SQL Server).

Comment: @Rekshino you are wrong. The right question is *Why limit to one thread at a time?*

Comment: @TsahiAsher that means adding another column that is nothing to do with the data being modeled, for tracking the DMLs performed, when it's fine to use the data being modeled to achieve optimistic concurrency? Microsoft don't use rowversion (ADO.NET DataSet optimistic conncurrency is achieved as I've shown here); why should i?

Comment: @CaiusJard ADO.NET DataSet is ancient tech. I haven't used it in 10 years (I use EF). Yes, you would add a `rowversion` column, keep it in a hidden input on your page, and send it back with the data to make sure it hasn't changed since you got the data. This will save you from updating your WHERE clause each time you add a field, and probably perform much better than e.g. string comparison.

Comment: Sounds so good, I'm amazed that Microsoft haven't made it a universal feature, a virtual hidden column on every table that you can select at will. I wonder why they didn't do that...

Comment: @CaiusJard https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392764/ef-core-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-does-not-work-as-expected.
Want similar functionality

Comment: OK, so why not implement it? That question you linked proposes the sort of concurrency checking I (and by extension Tsahi) was recommending; that you track what the old value is and send that back to the db as a condition of the update, and handle the Concurrency exception that comes when the command updates 0 records

Comment: But... if you check the comments of that answer, the user who asked question has not changed anything

Answer (score 0):

Just technical solution to the question as it was formulated. It doesn't pretend to be architectural correct.

If you have several `await` calls, then you can't be sure, that all of them wil be executed on the same thread. These are principals of async pattern. If you want the method inner be called on the same(not on the single) thread, then you have to get rid of inner `await` calls, make appropriate methods synchronous(don't make a synchronous wrapper because it can lead to the dead locks [Should I expose synchronous wrappers for asynchronous methods?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/)) and leave only one `await` on the top level.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ApproveEntity([FromBody] Entity[] entities)
{
    return await Task.Run<IActionResult>(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            //Do synchronisation if needed here.

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    if (this.ValidateConcurrencyForWriteBack(Entity))
                    {

                        return this.BadRequest("Concurrency Error : Somebody else has already done this action. Please refresh and try again.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (Entity.SupportingDocuments?.Count > 0)
                            {
                                this.UploadDocumentsToBlob(Entity, user);//Change method to be synchronous.
                                this.Uow.Commit();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw;
                        }

                        this.BulkChallengeApproveReject(entities, user);//Change method to be synchronous.
                    }
                }
    }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return this.Ok(Entity)
    });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47392764/ef-core-dbupdateconcurrencyexception-does-not-work-as-expected