# EF Core Fluent API: two ways of concurrency token using for the timestamp

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I see two ways to do it from two sources:

[First](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .Property(p => p.Timestamp)
        .IsRowVersion();
}
```

[Second](http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency):

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Author>()
        .Property(a => a.RowVersion)
        .IsConcurrencyToken()
        .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate();
}
```

Both cases I use `byte[]` for the property.

What is difference and what is preferable?

Comment: A duplicate methinks.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330015/optimistic-concurrency-isconcurrencytoken-and-rowversion

Comment: In few words, if you're working with early version for SQL Server you should to use IsRowVersion() (Timestamp) and if you're working with most recent version for SQL Server you should to use IsConcurrenyToken

Comment: More details on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency

Comment: @H.Herzl it is my first link in the topic.

Comment: Which type in database? If you have rowversion, then use IsConcurrencyToken

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but if anyone else happens upon it, since introduction in EF Core 1.1 'IsRowVersion' is just a wrapper around 'IsConcurrencyToken' and 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate'. IsRowVersion will automatically select the correct datatype of rowversion for the column also which I don't think is the case for IsConcurrencyToken.