# Select and update by one transaction

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, transactions, entity-framework-6

I have some product to sale and I want to check existing of product in store.
I use Entity Framework and SQL server.
I want some think like this.

```
IF ((SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM tblProduct WHERE Id =1)>0)
UPDATE tblProduct
SET count = count -1
WHERE Id = 1
```

But this is not in one transaction and when users want to buy in same time, I can't check it correctly.I tried this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
IF ((SELECT TOP 1 Amount FROM tblProduct WHERE Id =1)>0)
    UPDATE tblProduct
    SET count = count -1
    WHERE Id = 1
COMMIT
```

but is not true.How can I do it in entity framework.
Thanks

Comment: Its hard to know what you are after, however I ""think"" you might be interested in optimistic concurrency,

Comment: I want to any user can't buy product when count of product is equal to 0

Comment: What do you mean by `but is not true`? It is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand you are trying to decrement product count on every sell operation.
You need to do this atomically because you need to avoid selling a product which out of stock.

There are several options like optimistic lock with keeping version on your data, or distributed lock for providing one buy operation on an item.

In sql you can run update statement with versioning like below:

```
update [table]
set count = count - 1
where id=1 and count=5 and version=3
```

Every update locks the row so if another update request comes in action it waits current update and when executed it affects 0 row.

You can also use a distributed lock with redis and lock the process itself.

It depends on requirements, use cases and your resources.

### Update

For doing this using entity framework, if you use code first you can do the below approach:

```
// add the below property to your entity
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

with fluent api:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(s => s.RowVersion).IsConcurrencyToken();
    //modelBuilder.Entity<YourEntity>().Property(s => s.RowVersion).IsRowVersion(); // in EF6 or EF Core
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Or you can use **[ConcurrencyCheck]** attribute:

```
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public int Version { get; set; }
[ConcurrencyCheck]
public int Count { get; set; }
```

EF will add this columns to where condition in your update queries. If affected row count is 0 EF throws **DbUpdateConcurrencyException** you need to catch it.

Take a look for further information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency

[Optimistic concurrency: IsConcurrencyToken and RowVersion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330015/optimistic-concurrency-isconcurrencytoken-and-rowversion)

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/817432/Optimistic-Concurrency-in-Entity-Framework-Code-Fi

http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/14e67064-634c-4206-9eca-a42d3739594a.aspx

Comment: Thanks,How can I do it in EF?

Answer (score 1):

You can try some other ways of implementing this. For example, perform the update only, when there is quantity:

```
UPDATE tblProduct
SET count = count -1
WHERE Id = 1
    AND Amount > 0;
```

In this way, there is no need from the `select` statement. Or, you can add a `check constraint` to ensure `count` is always `> 0` and leave the SQL Engine to apply the ACID properties. If somehow, a user (transaction) try to decrease the count below 0, an error is going to be thrown and you can catch the error in the application (for example).

Comment: Thanks,How can I do it in EF?

Comment: @AmirhosseinYari To create check constraint on your table?

Comment: No,To update enitty with out load it.like this "SET count = count -1"

Comment: How you are executing the queries against the database - ExecuteSqlCommand?