# IsConcurrencyToken(true) does not actually check concurrency tokens

Tags: ef-core-3.0

I have a property configured like this:

```
public byte[] Timestamp { get; set; }
```

And then in my DbContext, i use the Fluent API like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyClass>()
.Property(x => x.Timestamp)
.IsRowVersion()
.IsConcurrencyToken(true);
```

So naturally i went ahead and wrote a unit test, ensuring that an entity with a wrong timestamp set would not get saved. I used Sqlite and some custom Sql to make RowVersion work in Unit Tests but to my surprise i never got an exception. Then, i tested it in our application, and i also did not get an exception when a wrong Timestamp was set on the entity.

```
var myInstance = await myDbContext.Instances
.Include(x => x...)
.Include(x => x...)
.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == id);

// set other values, add new entities to relationships, aso

myInstance.Timestamp = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

await myDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I am clearly missing something here. I thought configuring `IsRowVersion` would be enough to force EF Core to include a `WHERE Timestamp =` clause in the `UPDATE` but it seems like thats not the case. As you can see, i also tried calling `IsConcurrencyToken` (even with its default value of `true`, just to be sure) but to no avail.

Edit: I have worked "around" it now by including the Timestamp in my `SingleAsync` call, but this still leaves me unsure if its still possible to not get a concurrency exception, as the `Timestamp` set on my entity is apparently not checked at all when saving?

Comment: You should remove `.IsConcurrencyToken(true)`. It seems that it overrides `IsRowVersion` while the later is [what you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417945/861716).

Comment: @GertArnold removing / adding it does actually nothing, as it just creates an empty migration. Seems like the reason is a known behavior of ef core https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18505

Comment: Then `.IsRowVersion()` apparently takes precedence. You should have a `rowversion` field in the database. For testing you better run a raw SQL update statement on the same record before saving changes. That's closer to reality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known behavior of EF core, as documented here:

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/18505

Manually changing the value of the token is considered to be a no-op, as the original value that was queried from the database is being used for a concurrency check. Manually changing the value does nothing, as it is effectively being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible to manually set the token's value and have EF Core's optimistic concurrency check fail if the database has a newer version of the entity:

```cs
db.Entry(entity).Property(nameof(Entity.ConcurrencyToken)).OriginalValue = entity.ConcurrencyToken;
```

As per [this comment](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/18505#:%7E:text=db.Entry(entity).Property(nameof(Entity.ConcurrencyToken)).OriginalValue%20%3D%20entity.ConcurrencyToken%3B) in [@user604613's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58745317)