# Entity Framework .NET Core not throwing DbUpdateConcurrencyException

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Simple Windows Forms program with EF dataset built from a SQL Server database.

If I load the form, which shows all current values in the `StudentsTable`, then immediately, using SSMS, change a student's GPA in the underlying SQL Server table, and then use the form to change that's student's GPA, it accepts the change and does not throw the `DbUpdateConcurrencyException`.

Here is the SQL Server table:

[image: SSMS table design]

I used Visual Studio `Scaffold-DbContext` command to to create the models based on my database.

Here is the resulting class created from the database table

```
 public partial class StudentsTable
 {
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Lname { get; set; } = null!;
    public decimal Gpa { get; set; }
    public int MajorId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Updated { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual MajorTable Major { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

And here is the `DbContext`:

```
public partial class StudentDbContext : DbContext
{
    public StudentDbContext()
    {
    }

    public StudentDbContext(DbContextOptions<StudentDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MajorTable> MajorTables { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StudentsTable> StudentsTables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)

        => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("xxxxxxxxxxxxx;Database=StudentDB;Trusted_Connection=True; TrustServerCertificate=True");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<MajorTable>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.MajorId);

            entity.ToTable("MajorTable");

            entity.Property(e => e.MajorId).HasColumnName("MajorID");
            entity.Property(e => e.Major).HasMaxLength(50);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentsTable>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.StudentId);

            entity.ToTable("StudentsTable");

            entity.Property(e => e.StudentId).HasColumnName("StudentID");
            entity.Property(e => e.Fname).HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(e => e.Gpa)
                .HasColumnType("numeric(18, 0)")
                .HasColumnName("GPA");
            entity.Property(e => e.Lname).HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(e => e.MajorId).HasColumnName("MajorID");
            entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
                .IsRowVersion()
                .IsConcurrencyToken();

            entity.HasOne(d => d.Major).WithMany(p => p.StudentsTables)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.MajorId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK_StudentsTable_MajorTable");
        });

        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }

    partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
}
```

My database timestamp column resulted in the model having a property called `Updated` which is correctly tagged as both an `IsRowVersion` and `IsConcurrency`.

Here is the C# code that does the update:

```
int newGPA;  //Variable to hold textBox input

if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out newGPA))
{
    var selected = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
    int selectedStudentId = (int)selected.Cells["StudentId"].Value;
    var selectedEvent =
        (from eachStudent in myContext.StudentsTables
            where eachStudent.StudentId == selectedStudentId
            select eachStudent).Single();
    selectedEvent.Gpa = newGPA;   //Edit one object

    try
    {
        myContext.SaveChanges();        // Save Changes
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is there some other setting I have to make in the C# code, or in the SQL Server database to "turn on" concurrency exceptions?

Comment: Why `Updated` is `byte[]`? Correct to appropriate type. Concurrency works IF property `Updated` is changed by someone else before your update. Also, you should add to your your code `selectedEvent.Update = DateTime.Now` or with other value with - it will force to save concurrency token.

Comment: `Updated` is SQL datatype `timestamp` in the underlying DB. (which does get changed every time I save new data or modify it using SSMS. I The scaffolding made that a C# byte array in the model. I did add code to change the 'Updated` value before doing the `SaveChanges` but still no exception.

Comment: [Only use `IsRowVersion`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31417945/861716).

Comment: Changed the code based on Gert comment  and removed the ``IsConcurrencyToken`` property.  Code works as before, that is, not detecting the first concurrency error but then catching them all from then on.

Answer (score 0):

I almost fixed it.  I edited the `StudentDbContext` file and changed

```
entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
    .IsRowVersion()
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

to

```
entity.Property(e => e.Updated)
    .IsRowVersion()
    .IsConcurrencyToken(true);
```

Now if I run 2 copies of the program, after they both start and show identical GPA numbers, if I update the GPA from 1 copy, and then update the same value from the 2nd copy, instead of an Exception, the 2nd copy "wins", but then if I continue to do updates from either, it does correctly throw the DbUpdateConcurrencyException every time thereafter. Why it fails to detect it the first time but then works from then on is a new mystery.